# Swipe-to-remove on a nested RecyclerView disables scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper, nestedrecyclerview

I'm sure there is a simple solution of which I'm just not aware. I have a nested `RecyclerView` like this. 
[image]
The outer `RecyclerView` has vertical scrolling with an attached `ItemTouchHelper` so that swiping left triggers swipe-to-delete behavior. The inner `RecyclerView` has horizontal scrolling.

Problem: swiping behavior in the `ViewHolder`, including trying to scroll the `RecyclerView` therein, triggers the swiping behavior.

Solution?: disable swipe-to-delete behavior for part of the `ViewHolder`. In this case, it would be disabled if the `RecyclerView` is scrolled/swiped. Conversely, it can only be enabled if a view inside the ViewHolder is swiped, like the header.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got any solution.If you got please let me know.